# How to count maximum continuous ones/zeros in a bit array in verilog

Tags: verilog

For a reg array, I want to count maximum continuous ones in them.

for example

```
reg [15:0] bit_array;
bit_array = 16'b1001_1111_1100_0100;
```

the result should be 7.

If I want to do the same thing on a 256-bit or even longer reg array,
is there any way to implement it in one or several cycle? (1GHz, 16nm FF+)

Edit 1:

The real problem is I want to find the largest continuous free memory size.
The 16-bit register array represent a 64KByte meomry, every bit represent a 4KByte memory block, 1'b1 means already allocated, 1'b0 means free.
So, the maximum count of continuous ones shows the largest size of free memory that can be allocated once.

My consideration about this is to perform a leading zero count to the register array, like following:

```
assign count = lzc(bit_array);  // lzc is a function to count leading zeros
always @(posedge clk) begin
    if(count >max_count)
        max_count <= count;
    bit_array <= {bit_array[0],bit_array[15:1]};
end
```

But the problem is it'll take 16 cycles for this, if I want to perform this on a 256-bit register array, it will cost 256 cycles, which is not acceptable.

So, please tell me there is a better way to do this.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Iterate and count.

Comment: Show some attempts to solve the problem. Otherwise we are assuming you want us to give you the code and do your homework for you.

Comment: You can do just as you illustrated or 'unroll the loop' and do two rotates, counts, and compares per clock.  Or 4, 8, 16, all the way up to 256.  In the extreme case you'll do it all in one clock, but will infer a huge amount of logic and almost certainly not meet timing, even in your fancy process.  It's up to you to trade off gate area vs. performance/latency.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will count maximum consecutive 1's in 1 cycle combinatorially, you can potentially break this loop to meet timing:

```
for(i=1;i<16;i=i+1) begin
    if(bit_array[i] == 1 && bit_array[i-1] == 1) begin
        count = count+1;
    else begin
        count = 0;
    end
end
```